# How to mock an object property which gets defined inside the class?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito

Consider the following class :-

```
class SomeClass {
    private val someData = Config.getData()
    
    suspend fun something() {
        return someData.someFunction()
    }
}
```

Config is an object that contains some data which is required by the property `someData`. I want `Config.getData()` to return some data that I have defined in the test case. But as `someData` is not passed in the constructor of `SomeClass` and since there isn't any setter method for `someData` as well, I cannot return custom `someData`. I neither want to change the `SomeClass` code, nor do I want to use PowerMock. Any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: can you use `mockk`?

Comment: would mockk solve my problem? i am already using it for other test cases

Comment: then you can use `mockkStatic ` method to mock `getData()` function